# Issue In Links after migrating from Live server to Localhost XAMPP

Tags: migration, localhost

I have migrated more than 50 websites from Live server to Localhost in my career but have not faced this issue till now.
I used ALL IN ONE WP MIGRATION to export the data from live server.
I replaced the url during export process.

```
http://www.example.com/ to http://localhost/example/
```

I imported the data in my fresh wordpress installation in my localhost. Every thing went fine. My home page loads fine as well.
But when I click the home page logo which should redirect to http://localhost/example/ but redirects to http://localhost/dashboard of XAMPP.
When I click the menu item -> Services which should redirect to http://localhost/example/services but redirects to http://localhost/services.

I tried changing the Site Address Url and Wordpress Address Url to http://localhost/example/.

My .htaccess file.

```
# BEGIN WordPress
# The directives (lines) between "BEGIN WordPress" and "END WordPress" are
# dynamically generated, and should only be modified via WordPress filters.
# Any changes to the directives between these markers will be overwritten.
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
RewriteBase /example/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /example/index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

go to PHPMyAdmin and click your database then check wp_options -> siteurl,
it should be http://localhost/example/

PHPMyAdmin -> open_database -> wp_options -> siteurl

Comment: The correct values are site_url and home_url, both need editing and there might also be hardcoded values in the wp_config.php file.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by running an SQL query in phpMyAdmin. Make sure you have selected your local site’s database and then click on SQL.

[image]

In phpMyAdmin’s SQL screen copy and paste this code, make sure that you replace example.com with your live site’s URL and http://localhost/example' with the local server URL of your site.

```
UPDATE wp_options SET option_value = replace(option_value, 'https://www.example.com', 'http://localhost/example') WHERE option_name = 'home' OR option_name = 'siteurl';
  
UPDATE wp_posts SET post_content = replace(post_content, 'https://www.example.com', 'http://localhost/example');
  
UPDATE wp_postmeta SET meta_value = replace(meta_value,'https://www.example.com','hhttp://localhost/example')
```

This query will replace refences to your live site’s URL from database and replace it with the localhost URL.

Comment: The third query can break sites really quick. Whenever WP stores array as data, it gets serialized. Doing simple string replacement inside a serialized string will likely break it. Instead, I suggesst using WP CLI or plugins like Better Search Replace to do this task.